# Google Maps V2 epoly2 by Mike How to get states xml

Tags: javascript, maps

I am curious about http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml

how did he generate the states i would like to generate it for Canada... but cant figure out where on google he found that xml or how he generated it.. any ideas?

Comment: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly2.htm is the sample code

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but there are various Creative Commons and ODC sources for data like this, such as those on [libremap](http://libremap.org/data/boundary/).

I don't have the time to google around for Canadian data, but I'm sure it's out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find gml files here which are actual xml files.

http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/search.do?produit=cgn&decoupage=province&language=en